# How to deploy the MERN full stack app with backend in bitnami nginx

Tags: nginx, deployment, ubuntu-14.04, bitnami, mern

Hi I dont want to use any clouldbase services for deployment. I have created react create app with backend (MERN STACK). I want to deploy it in my local server bitnami nginx server (ubuntu 14.04) . I dont find any thing about bitnami configuration. can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install bitnami stack from their website https://bitnami.com/stack/nginx/installer

You can find Get-Started Docs on their site as well https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/get-started/

> I want to deploy it in my local server

Hosting/Deploying Application from local server is really bad idea, Because usually your computer or your router is sitting behind the ISP's NAT and You don't have control over general ports (80, 443) which means your cant use those ports. it is generally the case with IPv4 addresses. ISP's do that to save their IPv4 addresses. this is not generally the case with IPv6.

Also (in most cases) your IP address is dynamic, which means it keeps changing overtime. If you are planning to use a domain for your application then you will also need and dynamic DNS service which usually aren't free.
On top of that Home broadband upstream speeds are very poor and low. Also you will have to keep your local server up 24/7.
You might wanna change your mind.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have the bitnami nginx sever with node v8 , mongo v4 and npm 6. how to build and deploy my react app....

Comment: i have bitnami nginx server in VM

Comment: you can use nginx as front-end server and use node as backend. use proxy_pass module (https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) to proxy the traffic to your app